# best way to remove file extension

Tags: ruby, filenames, file-extension

What is the shortest way to remove file extension? this is what I have tried:

```
file = "/home/usr/my_file.xml"
file = File.basename(file)
file.slice! File.extname(file)   #=> my_file
```

Comment: that answer is for `c#`

Comment: This is NOT a duplicate question! It asks for the extension to be chopped off while keeping the path, while the other question requires getting rid of the extension AND the path.

Comment: @AsfandQazi The example gives just the filename, though (`#=> my_file`).

Answer (score 65, accepted):

Read the documentation of [`File::basename`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/File.html#method-c-basename) :

> basename(file_name [, suffix] ) → base_name
>
> Returns the last component of the filename given in file_name, which can be formed using both File::SEPARATOR and File::ALT_SEPARETOR as the separator when File::ALT_SEPARATOR is not nil. **If *suffix* is given and present at the end of file_name, it is removed.**

```
file = "/home/usr/my_file.xml"
File.basename(file,File.extname(file)) # => "my_file"
```

Comment: Is there a way to achieve the same thing but preserving the path ? #=> /home/usr/my_file

Comment: @zml No direct approach. But `File.join(File.dirname("file/path"), File.basename('file/path', '.*'))`

Comment: `path[0..-(File.extname(path).length + 1)]`

Comment: Another way:`file.sub(/#{File.extname(file)}$/, '')`

Comment: You can do: file.sub(/\.[^.\/]*\Z/, '') to chop off the extension. It'll work for paths like /foo/bar/baz. and /foo/bar.baz/quux as well.

Comment: This seems very un-rubyesque. I'm surprised there's not a better built-in method

Comment: @zml yes there is: `file = "/home/usr/my_file.xml" <newline>
file.slice! File.extname(file)   #=> "/home/usr/my_file"`